# android get rect() issue

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to perfect the drag and drop app which for a week that I've been doing.
If I drop the droppable object onto the drop target, the imageview should fit into the drop target. 
 This is the screenshot:

[image]

as you can see, I have 2 droppable objects to drop onto the target.

FYI, this is the code I'm working on:

```
   @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView img, img2, img3=null;
AbsoluteLayout aLayout;
int status = 0;
private boolean dragging = false;
private Rect hitRect = new Rect();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    aLayout= (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.absLayout);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    img3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            status = 1;
            Log.i("ImageStatus","1st image moved" + status);

            return false;
        }
    });

    img2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            status = 2;
            Log.i("ImageStatus","2nd image moved" + status);

            return false;
        }
    });

    aLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("touch", "touched here" + event);
            boolean eventConsumed = true;
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();

            if(status == 1) // any event from down and move
            {
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int)event.getX()-img.getWidth()/2,
                        (int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2);
                img.setLayoutParams(lp);

            } else if(status == 2){
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            (int)event.getX()-img2.getWidth()/2,
                            (int)event.getY()-img2.getHeight()/2);
                    img2.setLayoutParams(lp);
            } else {
                Log.i("Nothing", "Nothing");
            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                //status = 0;
                drop(v, event);

                /*
                img.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                img2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                if(status == 1){
                    if (dragging) {
                        img3.getHitRect(hitRect);
                        if (hitRect.contains(x, y)){
                            setSameAbsoluteLocation(img, img3);
                            }
                        }
                } else if (status == 2){
                    if (dragging) {
                        img3.getHitRect(hitRect);
                        if (hitRect.contains(x, y)){
                            setSameAbsoluteLocation(img2, img3);
                            }
                    }
                } 
            } */
            //dragging = false; 

        }

            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void setSameAbsoluteLocation(View v1, View v2) {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp2 = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v2.getLayoutParams();
    setAbsoluteLocation(v1, alp2.x, alp2.y);
}

private void setAbsoluteLocationCentered(View v, int x, int y) {
    setAbsoluteLocation(v, x - v.getWidth() / 2, y - v.getHeight() / 2);
}

private void setAbsoluteLocation(View v, int x, int y) {
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    alp.x = x;
    alp.y = y;
    v.setLayoutParams(alp);
}

private boolean checkHit(MotionEvent event, View hit){      
    Rect rhit = new Rect(hit.getLeft(), hit.getTop(), hit.getRight(), hit.getBottom());
    return rhit.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY());
}

private boolean checkHit(View v, View hit){
    Rect rv = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    Rect rhit = new Rect(hit.getLeft(), hit.getTop(), hit.getRight(), hit.getBottom());
    return rv.intersect(rhit);
}

private void drop(View v, MotionEvent event){
    checkHit(v, img3);
    checkHit(event, img3);
    // Do some for looping, do some other magic, do what you want
    if(status == 1){
        setSameAbsoluteLocation(img, img3);
    }
    else if (status == 2){
        setSameAbsoluteLocation(img2, img3);
    } else {
        status = 0;
    } 
}
```

But when I drag away the object onto the drop target, it's just staying there :( How can I let the dropped object return to its default position? I'd truly appreciate your help. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm doing this in pre-Honeycomb versions like Gingerbread.

Comment: +1 because a image is always good to explain better...

Comment: @Seraphim Hello thanks for the +1, have you got an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about drag and drop because just never had to use it. Just some interesting links: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html, http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/ and http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/

Comment: Thanks for the links you provided, but I want to do it in GingerBread without using ClipData

Comment: So explain it in your question so other users will not respond providing unusefull like i did! ;)